# Ionic2 dualknob range value inside a formcontrol using angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to get form values as an object. Except for dualknob range i am getting values as expected.Can any one guide me how to get ionic2 dualKnob value using form control.

This is my html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="complexForm" (change)="submitForm(complexForm.value)">   
 <div class="form-group">
    <ion-list-header class="search-range">
      <span><strong>Age</strong></span>
      <ion-item>
       <ion-range dualKnobs="true" pin="true" min="0" max="100" debounce="500" [(ngModel)]="ageValue" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (ionChange)="onDataChange(complexForm.value)"></ion-range>
       </ion-item>
    </ion-list-header>
     </div>
 </form>
```

but, I am getting 'not a number' Object in my console as:- Object {lower: NaN, upper: NaN}

This is how i am trying to get form values

```
this.complexForm = fb.group({
  'interest': 'Mingle',
  'male': false,
  'female': false,
  'range': this.rangeValue,
  'agerange':  [{lower: this.ageValue, upper: this.ageValue}]
})
```

Comment: ion-range is part of formGroup? I dont see `formControlName`..

Comment: try `  'agerange':  [{lower: Number(this.ageValue), upper: Number(this.ageValue)}]`

Comment: How can i write formControlName for ionic components. For normal input type= range I can use [formControl]="complexForm.controls['interest']"

Comment: so..how is agerange bound to your ion-range? and what type is `ageValue` declared as?

Comment: you could try similar for ion-range.. not sure

Comment: ageValue is of type number. If I  try same for ion-range its not working..getting error as not a type of ion-range

Comment: Thank u Suraj for your response. I cleared the issue by giving <ion-range dualKnobs="true" pin="true"  min="21" max="72" step="3" [(ngModel)]="ageValue"(change)="onDataChange(complexForm.value)" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['agerange']"></ion-range>

Comment: if its solved you can add the answer to the question and mark it for others with the issue..

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by :-

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <ion-list-header class="search-range">
      <span><strong>Age</strong></span>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-range dualKnobs="true" pin="true" min="18" max="75" step="3" [(ngModel)]="ageValue" (change)="onDataChange(complexForm.value)" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['agerange']"></ion-range>
       </ion-item>
    </ion-list-header>
     </div>

ageValue: any = { lower: 33, upper: 60 };
constructor( private fb: FormBuilder){
this.complexForm = fb.group({
  'interest': 'Mingle',
  'male': false,
  'female': false,
  'range': this.rangeValue,
  'agerange':   [{lower: this.ageValue, upper: this.ageValue}]
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

> this.complexForm.get('form-group.ageValue').value.lower

in the component, and

> {{ complexForm.controls.form-group.controls.ageValue._value.lower }}

in the template.

And you do not need the [(ngModel)] of course, only formGroup, formGroupName and formControlName.